# How can the JDFlipNumberView frame be changed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I downloaded JDFlipNumberView [from here](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDFlipNumberView).

It works but there is a problem with the frame. To change the frame the developer has said to use:

```
flipNumberView.frame = CGRectMake(10,100,300,100);
```

but when I do this it doesn't change.

PS: when I put `NSLog(@"%@",flipNumberView.frame);` it returns `null`.

How can I change the frame?

Comment: flipNumberView.frame = CGRectMake(10,100,300,100);
 this right then do you want to re-size it?  ??

Answer (score 0):

"fram' is not a string, it is structure's object.so if you want see frame. you can use it.

```
  NSLog(@"Width = %f",btn.frame.size.width);
  NSLog(@"height = %f",btn.frame.size.height);

  NSLog(@"x = %f",btn.frame.origin.x);
  NSLog(@"y = %f",btn.frame.origin.y);
```

may be it help for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the example project, you need to deactivate the `layoutSubviews:` method first. It resets the frame on every relayout.

Otherwise just set a new frame.